# Python Reducing Nested Loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, nested-loops

So I am working on a UVA problem and I have 4 nested loops to iterate over a list of polygons (each polygon contains a list of points where each point contains an integer x and y to represent it's coordinates, i.e polygon[0] is a point which coordinates are polygon[0].x and polygon[0].y).

I am trying to reduce the number of for loops in the program in order to make it more efficient and have a lower runtime. My code is as follows:

```
for i in range(len(polygons)): # iterate over all the different polygons in the test case
    for j in range(i+1, len(polygons)): # iterate over all the different polygons in the test case but starting from the second, in order to make comparations between polygons i and j
        for a in range(len(polygons[i])):
            if (isInside(polygons[i][a].x, polygons[i][a].y, polygons[j])):
                union(i,j)
        for a in range(len(polygons[j])):
            if (isInside(polygons[j][a].x, polygons[j][a].y, polygons[i])):
                union(i,j)
        f = 1
        for a in range(len(polygons[i])): # iterate over all the different points in the polygon i
            for b in range(len(polygons[j])): # iterate over all the different points in the polygon j
                if (f!=0):
                    if(doIntersect(polygons[i][a], polygons[i][(a+1)%len(polygons[i])],polygons[j][b], polygons[j][(b+1)%len(polygons[j])])): # check if every single pair of line segments, each one made up of two points, intersect with each other
                        union(i,j) # the two line segments intersect so we join them by using union
                        f = 0
```

And I tried to make it more efficient by using itertools.product as follows:

```
def solve():
global polygons, p

ranges = [range(len(polygons)), range(1,len(polygons))]

for i, j in product(*ranges):
    for a in range(len(polygons[i])):
        if (isInside(polygons[i][a].x, polygons[i][a].y, polygons[j])):
            union(i,j)
    for a in range(len(polygons[j])):
        if (isInside(polygons[j][a].x, polygons[j][a].y, polygons[i])):
            union(i,j)
    f = 1
    ranges2 = [range(len(polygons[i])), range(len(polygons[j]))]
    for a,b in product(*ranges2):
        if (f!=0):
            if(doIntersect(polygons[i][a], polygons[i][(a+1)%len(polygons[i])],polygons[j][b], polygons[j][(b+1)%len(polygons[j])])): # check if every single pair of line segments, each one made up of two points, intersect with each other
                union(i,j) # the two line segments intersect so we join them by using union
                f = 0
```

Anyhow my code is having the same runtime in both cases, is there a way to reduce the number of nested loops for my algorithm?

Thanks in advance for any given help, much appreciated

Comment: You don't have a product for the outer loop, you are producing *combinations*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your two outer loops are creating *combinations* of lists; use the [`itertools.combinations()` iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) for those. Your innermost double loop produces the *carthesian product*, so use the [`itertools.product()` iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).

Don't generate indices with `range(), just loop directly over the polygon lists; use`enumerate()` to add indices rather than make indices work the other way around.

To pair up sections, the [`pairwise()` recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) from the `itertools` recipes section; that'll let you get all segments to work with. To circle round to the start again (pairing up the last coordinate with the first), just append a list with the first element to the end.

Once you get rid of nested loops, you can use `break` to end them rather than use a flag variable.

```
from itertools import combinations, product

def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)

for (i, a_poly), (j, b_poly) in combinations(enumerate(polygons), 2):
    for a in a_poly:
        if isInside(a.x, a.y, b_poly):
            union(i, j)
    for b in b_poly:
        if isInside(b.x, b.y, a_poly):
            union(j, i)

    # attach the first element at the end so you go 'round'
    a_segments = pairwise(a_poly + a_poly[:1])
    b_segments = pairwise(b_poly + b_poly[:1])
    for a_seg, b_seg in product(a_segments, b_segments):
        if doIntersect(*a_seg, *b_seg):
            union(i,j)
            break
```

In fact, once you have determined something is a union, you don't have to continue with the rest of the tests. You could use the [`any()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) to stop testing the `isInside()` and `doIntersect` functions early:

```
for (i, a_poly), (j, b_poly) in combinations(enumerate(polygons), 2):
    if any(isInside(a.x, a.y, b_poly) for a in a_poly):
        union(i, j)
        break  # union found, no need to look further

    for any(isInside(b.x, b.y, a_poly) for b in b_poly):
        union(i, j)
        break  # union found, no need to look further

    # attach the first element at the end so you go 'round'
    a_segments = pairwise(a_poly + a_poly[:1])
    b_segments = pairwise(b_poly + b_poly[:1])
    if any(doIntersect(*a_seg, *b_seg) 
           for a_seg, b_seg in product(a_segments, b_segments)):
        union(i,j)
```

This is not only far more readable now, it should also be more efficient!