# How to reduce the nested for Loop complexity to a single loop in python?

Tags: python, nested-loops

```
for i in range(0,x):
        for j in range(0,y):
            if (i+j)%2 == 0:
```

Think of something like tossing two dices at the same time and finding if the sum on the dices is an even number but here's the catch, a dice has 6 sides but here the two can have any number of sizes, equal and not equal even!
Can anyone suggest how to merge it under one loop because I can't think of any?

Comment: What are you *trying to do*? Without context: here's a program that reduces the complexity: `pass`

Comment: We don't know what you're trying to do - for example, what if the condition isn't satisfied? Do you use any of the values? Or do you want to generate only the values of `j` that satisfy the condition?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Reducing Nested Loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43921489/python-reducing-nested-loops)

Comment: What you've written suggests you're working with a grid, and if so then definitely keep it the way it is since its most readable. Turning it into one loop will ultimately have the same complexity (since you'd be using `range(x*y)`) and have an insignificant change in performance :)

Comment: No, like think of something like tossing two dices at the same time and finding if the sum on the dices is even number but here's the catch, a dice has 6 sides but here the two can have any number of sizes, equal and not equal even!

Answer (score 2):

based on [Python combine two for loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9394803/python-combine-two-for-loops), you can merge two for loops in a single line by importing itertools as below:

```
import itertools

for i, j in itertools.product(range(0,x), range(0,y)):
    if (i+j)%2 == 0:
```

Comment: This doesn't change the algorithmic complexity.

Answer (score 2):

You can't get rid of the nested loop (you could hide it, like by using `itertool.product`, but it would still be executed somewhere, and the complexity would still be O(x * y)) but you can get rid of the condition, if you only need to generate the values of j that satisfy it, by adapting the range for `j`.

This way, you'll have about twice as less loops by avoiding the useless ones.

```
for i in range(0,x):
    for j in range(i%2,y, 2):
        print(i, j, i+j)
```

Output:

```
0 0 0
0 2 2
1 1 2
1 3 4
2 0 2
2 2 4
```

Answer (score 2):

For me its much cleaner to leave it as two loops. Its much more readable and easier to understand whats happening. However you could essentially do `x * y` then use divmod to calculate i and j

```py
x = 2
y = 3
for i in range(0,x):
        for j in range(0,y):
            print(i, j, i+j)

print("###")
for r in range(x*y):
    i, j = divmod(r, y)
    print(i, j, i + j)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
0 0 0
0 1 1
0 2 2
1 0 1
1 1 2
1 2 3
###
0 0 0
0 1 1
0 2 2
1 0 1
1 1 2
1 2 3
```

Comment: `arr1=[n for n in range(0,a)]`
`arr2=[n for n in range(0,b)]`
`lst1=list(combinations(arr1, 2))`
`lst2=list(combinations(arr2, 2))`
`lst=lst1+lst2`
`res = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(lst))`

It has an output like this-
[(0, 1),
 (0, 2),
 (0, 3),
 (0, 4),
 (1, 2),
 (1, 3),
 (1, 4),
 (2, 3),
 (2, 4),
 (3, 4),
 (0, 5),
 (0, 6),
 (0, 7),
 (0, 8),
 (1, 5),
 (1, 6),
 (1, 7),
 (1, 8),
 (2, 5),
 (2, 6),
 (2, 7),
 (2, 8),
 (3, 5),
 (3, 6),
 (3, 7),
 (3, 8),
 (4, 5),
 (4, 6),
 (4, 7),
 (4, 8),
 (5, 6),
 (5, 7),
 (5, 8),
 (6, 7),
 (6, 8),
 (7, 8)]