# Reducing nested loops in C++

Tags: c++, nested-loops, reducing

```
for(int i=1; i<=a;i++){
        for(int j=1;j<=b;j++){
            if((i+j)%2 == 0){
                count++;}}}
```

Can anyone reduce the Time complexity of this problem? I am finding great difficulty in doing it.

Comment: How many odd numbers in `[1, a]` and `[1, b]`? How many even numbers?

Comment: Hint, `even + even == even`, `odd + odd = even`, `even + odd == odd`

Comment: No this isn't the exact problem.

Comment: Well if you described what the problem is, we might be able to give you a better algorithm to do it.

Comment: Two x and y, to find the even pair sum such that 1≤a≤x, 1≤b≤y and a+b is even.

Comment: Our hints give `O(1)` complexity instead of your `O(n²)`.

Comment: @Jarod42 How did you do $O(n^2)$

Comment: @Kostas: it was on my (French) azerty keyboard.

Comment: `int count = a/2 * b/2 + (a+1)/2 * (b+1)/2`. Apparently you can't easily simplify things when floor division is involved. My regards to the compiler.

Comment: @Kostas or just `int count = (a*b)/2.`

Comment: You appear to have asked the same question in [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65212883). What you're asking about is actually an algorithm question, and the answer is going to be the same in every programming language. Perhaps you want to add the [tag:algorithm] tag?